# Filtering out specific rows - taking the first of each type of subject information

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I'm looking to take out the first row of each subjectID and to make it into the new dataset. Essentially, the numbers and letters represent a longitudinal study, but I only want the first test from each subject as a baseline dataframe.

My goal is to make this data below: **Lets name this dataframe as DF1**

| SubjectID | Sex | Age | Race | 100s of more columns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **WS11Q6Y-01** | F | 32 | C |  |
| WS11Q6Y-02 | F | 32 | C |  |
| **SEES45W-101** | M | 12 | B |  |
| SEES45W | M | 12 | B |  |
| SEES45W | M | 12 | B |  |
| **JWE98UW-03** | F | 45 | H |  |
| JWE98UW-W4 | F | 45 | H |  |

Look like this by only taking the first row of each type of name. What would be the most effective way in doing this? (columns bolded to help display what was filtered to the new dataframe)

**Ideally, I would like to make a new dataframe called DF2** (shown below)

| SubjectID | Sex | Age | Race | 100s of more columns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **WS11Q6Y-01** | F | 32 | C |  |
| **SEES45W-101** | M | 12 | B |  |
| **JWE98UW-03** | F | 45 | H |  |

Essentially, the goal is to extract the first letter series (ex. WS11Q6Y) of its type, including the other variables such that I get one subject in the list.

Any suggestions on addressing this would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the substring of 'SubjectID' and use that as grouping variable to `slice` the first row.  Here, the regex used match the `-` followed by any characters (`.*`) till the end (`$`) of the string, thus making the 'SubjectID' values similar without those, then do the grouping to return the first row with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(grp = str_remove(SubjectID, "-.*$")) %>%
    slice_head(n = 1) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  SubjectID   Sex     Age Race 
  <chr>       <chr> <int> <chr>
1 JWE98UW-03  F        45 H    
2 SEES45W-101 M        12 B    
3 WS11Q6Y-01  F        32 C
```

---

Or without using `group_by`, make use `duplicated` which returns a logical vector for duplicate elements on the substring of 'SubjectID', negate (`!`) so that TRUE -> FALSE and FALSE -> TRUE to get the first unique rows

```
df1 %>%
    filter(!duplicated(str_remove(SubjectID, "-.*$")))
```

---

Or this can be done in `base R` as well

```
subset(df1, !duplicated(sub("-.*$", "", SubjectID)))
     SubjectID Sex Age Race
1  WS11Q6Y-01   F  32    C
3 SEES45W-101   M  12    B
6  JWE98UW-03   F  45    H
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SubjectID = c("WS11Q6Y-01", "WS11Q6Y-02", "SEES45W-101", 
"SEES45W", "SEES45W", "JWE98UW-03", "JWE98UW-W4"), Sex = c("F", 
"F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F"), Age = c(32L, 32L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
45L, 45L), Race = c("C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "H", "H")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

**data.table**

using the approach of a respected @akrun

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[1], by = gsub("-.*$", "", SubjectID)][]
      gsub Sex Age Race
1: WS11Q6Y   F  32    C
2: SEES45W   M  12    B
3: JWE98UW   F  45    H
```